# Textview background - what's setting it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_banner"
        android:name="com.apps4care.mycarerecord.fragments.patientBannerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/patient_banner" >
    </fragment>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/top_banner" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:name="com.apps4care.mycarerecord.fragments.footerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/footer">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then add a number of fragments into the  that have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/documentFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsectionHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Section Heading Text Goes Here"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvsectionHTML"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvsectionHeading"  
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives a screen that looks like

[image]

My question is in three parts :

1) Where did the background color come from on the TextView. It is not set in the XML layout file or the code.

2) Why is the background color on the TextView not consistent. The bars lower down the screen are lighter, especially in the horizontal centre of the screen.

3) The Scrollview content is meant to stop above the "footer" fragment but it does not, the bottom of the content on the Scrollview is hidden behind the "footer" fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background for the TextView comes from it's (default) style which is transparent.

what you are seeing is the default background of activity in the Holo light theme. you can change it by overriding it in your theme, or setting a background color to the relative layout in you main layout file

Answer (score 0):

The TextView colour is consistent, but it the colour of your background page, the default colour, which has a glow towards the bottom (it is the page's default formatting). This happened to my application too. Try changing the background of your page and see if the issue is still there, it should go away.

Comment: I see how this might be the case - what I am puzzled about is how the textview has a background at all. I did not set one so where has it come from?

Comment: Good point, I'm baffled too, is it to do with your styles/themes? Maybe they're applying it to TextViews? If you need to you can always change the background of the TextView to white using android:background="#FFFFFF".